# How does gcc decide which libraries to implicitly include?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker, stm32

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857844/gcc-how-to-stop-malloc-being-linked/45858219?noredirect=1#comment78711469_45858219):

On an embedded project for a small micro I found my compiled code size was much larger than expected.  It turned out it was because I had included code that used assert().  The use of assert was appropriate in the included code but caused my compiled code size to almost double.

The question is not around if/when assert should be used but how the compiler/linker decides to include all the necessary overhead for assert.

My original question from the other post:

It would be helpful if someone could explain to me how gcc decides to include library functions when assert is called? I see that assert.h declares an external function __assert_func. How does the linker know to reference it from a library rather than just say "undefined reference to __asert_func"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When configuring a toolchain, the authors decide which libraries that should be linked to by default.

Often this is includes runtime startup/initializing code and a library named `libc` which includes an implementation of the C standard, and any other code the authors deem relevant (e.g. libc might also implement Posix, any custom board specific functions etc.) and for embedded targets it's not unusual to also link to a library implementing an RTOS for the target.

You can use the `-nodefaultlibs` flag to gcc to omit these default libraries at the linking stage.

In the case of assert(), it is a standard C macro/function , which is normally implemented in libc. assert() might print to `stdout` if it fails, so using assert() could pull in the entire stdio facility that implements FILE* handling/buffering, printf etc., all which is implemented in libc.

You can see the libraries that gcc links to by default if you run `gcc -v` for the linking stage.

Comment: That is pretty muchly exactly what it did.  Pulled in stdio and printf etc...  For some naive reason I had assumed that the linker needed to be told all libraries to link to, including libc...

Answer (score 4):

The `gcc` (or `g++`) command is simply a driver. It runs other programs, including the compiler proper (`cc1` for C code, `cc1plus` for C++ code) and the assembler and the linker.

What programs are run are determined by the [spec file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html) (and there is an implicit one, see the `-dumpspecs` [developer option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html#Developer-Options)). BTW, running `gcc` with the `-v` option displays the actual programs involved.

The `assert` macro is defined (see file `/usr/include/assert.h`) to do some check in `<assert.h>` only if `NDEBUG` is not a defined preprocessor symbol. On my Linux/Glibc system it can call a `__assert_failed` internal function from the C standard library. Citing [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html) documentation:

> If the macro `NDEBUG` is defined at the moment `<assert.h>` was last
>     included, the macro `assert()` generates no code, and hence does
>          nothing at all.

Some projects are compiling with `-DNDEBUG` their code in production mode.

You should read the [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter of the documentation.

Perhaps you want to [compile with `-ffreestanding`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html) to avoid any extra libraries, even the standard ones?

Answer (score 2):

On your embedded system linking is static. Static linking works as follows.

A static library is an archive of object files. The linker considers each object separately.

A referenced function or variable that is found in a static library is included in the resulting executable, together with the entire object file that contains the referenced symbol. Object files that don't contain referenced symbols are not pulled in.

This isn't by any way specific to gcc. Linkers work this way since the dawn of time.