# Disable default malloc with arm-none-eabi on cortex m3 (bare metal)

Tags: c, malloc, bare-metal

I want to provide my own or better no malloc function. So I want to make sure it's not linked at all.

I already pass `-nostdlib` and `--specs=nano.specs` to the linker.

When providing my own malloc function I get:
`` ../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7-m\libc_nano.a(lib_a-malloc.o): In function `malloc':
malloc.c:(.text.malloc+0x0): multiple definition of `malloc' ``

I'm looking for a way to skip linking of the `lib_a-malloc.o`

**As a clarification:** It's more about having no `malloc` at all than about providing my own implementation. Providing my own implementation was just to check if there already is one or for debugging purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you should rename your function to something else? It might be a good idea anyway, since it then will help readers of your code to understand that it's not the standard `malloc` function, and that will help the maintainability as well.

Comment: It's not about using my own malloc implementation, it's about not using the default anywhere. I want the linker to fail when ever someone is calling the default `malloc` implementation to avoid issues with the RTOS we are using.

Comment: Currently I think the only way is to recompile newlib my self without malloc and link against it. The arm-none-eabi toolchain seems to to provide options to use newlib without malloc.

Comment: That's one solution. Other possibilities include linker flags to either undefine certain symbols (I don't know if such exits) or override or replace the standard `malloc` with your own (I know there are ways to do it but I don't know how).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about linker flags: That's what I'm looking for, I will also dig into it later. Providing my own malloc would only work it the newlib implementation is declared weak, but it is not.
Maybe I can also handle the issue somehow in my linker file?

Comment: Did you ever find a nice way to prevent `malloc()` from being linked? I'm encountering a similar dilemma right now....

Answer (score 1):

Using the same name as a standard function's name is almost always a bad idea.

Even you, after some time not working on that project, will not remember that this `malloc()` you are reading in your code is not the `malloc()` that we all know and loved. Let aside anyone else.

So, for maintainability and readability, I suggest you name your function differently, plain example: `my_malloc()`.

PS: You might want to read [GCC - How to stop malloc being linked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857844/gcc-how-to-stop-malloc-being-linked)

Comment: Unless you want all binaries to use your version of malloc.

Comment: Yes that would be one case @perreal, that's why I said almost.